# How to fix "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Tags: python, python-packaging

I am creating a python package which follows the structure:

```
project
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── subpackage01
│       ├── functions01.py
│       ├── __init.py__
│       └── subpackage02
│           ├── functions02.py
│           ├── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
```

In `__main__.py` I have `from .subpackage01.functions01 import foo` which gives me the error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

If I remove the dot before subpackage01 it works but stops working in my pypi package. Removing the dot, building the package and uploading it gives me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subpackage01'`.

I can't understand the why, since in `functions01.py` I have relative imports for `subpackage02` that works with no problem. Also I can't figure out why it works when the package is built and doesn't in a local development environment.

Comment: Is the `__init__.py` spelled correctly in the `subpackage01` directory?

Answer (score 1):

Try `from subpackage01.functions01 import foo` it's a subtle difference by removing the leading dot from subpackage01.

Comment: But if I do it, after building the package for pipy it doesnt work